# How to compare the date today and to the date timestamp created_at using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to let the user to renew his/her application every 1 year. For example today is 2017-08-14 and if the date goes by 2018-08-14 the application will tell the user that he needs to renew his application.

```
@if ($application->created_at->todatestring() != 2018-08-14)
   <h1>You need to renew your application!</h1>
@endif
```

So by default its not just always 2018 to renew the application. So how will I get the value of the upcoming year next year? How do I increment the year or add it by 1

Looking for help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected `created_at` is a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) object:

```
@if ($application->created_at->addYear()->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::now()))
    <h1>You need to renew your application!</h1>
@endif
```

See more [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

Comment: Thanks! Btw how do I test it if it works cause if I changed the time settings in my machine my application always crash

Comment: Shouldn't logic be `->lt()`?